# How to fetch JSON API data and show that on Page using react.js

Tags: json, reactjs, api

I want to fetch all data from "https://blockchain.info/api/exchange_rates_api" and show that on Page. I tried it but got an error message. Here is my Code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
      this.state = {
        data: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() 
    {
      fetch("https://blockchain.info/ticker").
        then((Response) => Response.json()).
          then ((findresponse)=>
            {
              console.log(findresponse)
              this.setState({
                data:findresponse
                  });
            }) 
    }

    render() 
    {
      return(
        <div>
          {
            this.state.data.map((dynamicData, Key) =>
              <div>
                <span>{dynamicData}</span>
              </div>
            )
          }
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

I got an error in setState method. When I m trying to write without setState method, I got data in the console. But I want data on the page in Table form.

Comment: You say you're getting an error inside setState, can you show the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that what you receive as JSON response from api call is an **object** not **array**. Objects don't have defined `map` function. First you need to convert object into an array.

Comment: Thank You, sir but still facing problem

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an object from the API call but you need an array in order to use `map`, so you need to do this:

```
fetch("https://blockchain.info/ticker").
   then((Response) => Response.json()).
     then ((findresponse)=>
        {
          this.setState({
            data: [findresponse] //wrap findresponse brackets to put the response in an array
           });
        })
```

Comment: Thank You, Ma'am I have set data: [findresponse.data] but I faced problem in render() method plz help I want API data into page in table format.

Comment: @tshr `findresponse` does not have a  `.data` it's just `findresponse`. What is the problem in the render method? What do you mean by table format ?  in an HTML `<table>`?

Comment: yes Ma'am I have changed this.state { data: [findresponse] }